# UITableView and UIView in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I want to develop an iPad application. I have an `UIViewController` that contain `UITableView` and `UIView`, and in my file .xib I have these two controllers. In my `ViewController.h`: I have `UITableView *table` and `UIView *viewContent`.

In `ViewController.m`:  I developed functions that I need to load data into the table view. Now I need to pass data from `UITableView` to my `UIView`.  I use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but it doesn't work:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
     // I get the object activite : here no problem 
     IPADAG1Activity  *activite = [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc]init ];
     //now I instanciate my UIViewController wich contain  : uiview *contentview and uitableview
     GSAActivityViewController *activity = [[GSAActivityViewController alloc]init];
     //in uiview I add label "desc" that I affect the value of activite.DESCRIPTION
     activity.desc.text = activite.DESCRIPTION;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new viewController and add it to the tableView row or are you trying to access a viewController on another view?

Comment: It appears you need to simply add a new view to viewController rather than create a new viewController to hold the view.

Comment: @MarkM  : I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: You are creating a new viewController but you never add that viewController to the current view. Either add [self.view addSubview:activity.view]; or add it to your current cell. Or use a  @property and just store the reference to that view rather than creating it everytime in the didSelect method. Is the view inside the row?

Comment: side note: `UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc]init ];` this line is doing nothing other than creating a view that then gets demolished when this function ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that this code is part of you `GSAActivityViewController` class.  That being said, you do not need to create a new `GSAActivityViewController` and change the label on that controller, because you already have the controller initialized.

Here is what your code is doing:

```
 //This line is getting your IPADAG1Activity correctly it looks like, this is fine
 IPADAG1Activity  *activite = [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


 //This code is creating a brand new UIView called *contentView, but it never gets used.  I am guessing that you are getting a warning about an unused variable here. ?  This line does not need to be in the program as far as I can tell because you don't need to create a new contentView, you just need to use the on GSAActivityViewController
 UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc]init ];


 //The line below is creating a brand new instance of GSAActivityViewController, but you don't want a brand new isntance, you want to use this GSAActivityViewController that has already been initialized.  This line does not need to be in the program as fas as I can tell.
 //now I instanciate my UIViewController wich contain  : uiview *contentview and uitableview
 GSAActivityViewController *activity = [[GSAActivityViewController alloc]init];


 //Lastly, you are changing the text of desc on the new GSAActivityViewController that you created.  This controller did not need to be created and is not being used in any way other than this function block, so when you change the text on desc you are changing the text on something that has not been displayed and is just about to get tossed out when this function ends (Assuming ARC)
 //in uiview I add label "desc" that I affect the value of activite.DESCRIPTION
 activity.desc.text = activite.DESCRIPTION;
```

So to fix your problem, you can just use `self` to get the current `GSAActivityViewController`.  You do not need to initialize a new one (or a new `contentView`).

So here is how your code should look:

```
 IPADAG1Activity  *activite = [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 //in uiview I add label "desc" that I affect the value of activite.DESCRIPTION
 self.desc.text = activite.DESCRIPTION;
```

This answer is based on a few assumptions, primarily that `desc` is a label that is a property of the `GSAActivityViewController` and that this code resides inside the `GSAActivityViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

```
IPADAG1Activity  *activite = [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Are you getting the data in active.DESCRIPTION

the problem is here

```
 GSAActivityViewController *activity = [[GSAActivityViewController alloc]init];
 //in uiview I add label "desc" that I affect the value of activite.DESCRIPTION
activity.desc.text = activite.DESCRIPTION;
```

you have not added activity.view to self.view.

Comment: even if I chang it by a string : @"value" , the label dosen't take this value

Comment: activity represent my whole uiviewcontroller that contain : uiview and uitableview

Comment: then there is no need to create one more object of the same class

Comment: and you should use it directly

desc.text = activite.DESCRIPTION;

Comment: you think that I need only on my didselectrow to add desc.text = activite.DESCRIPTION , and the object concerned will be  be displayed on uiview ?

Comment: Yes try to use this because this is the label in the same class so there is no need to create another object of the same class.

Comment: I would probably use `self.desc.text = activite.DESCIRPTION`.  I always like to use `self.` to keep it clear that the object is a property of this particular controller and not just some local variable or something.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `tableView`s **`delegate`**:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Or, you could do so in IB:

[image]

Comment: Yes I did it , , my probleme is not in displaying data into my table, that is done . Now I need to pass these data to my uiview

Comment: @MMerou Are you using static or prototype tables?

Comment: prototype table .excuse me plz data are shown in the tableview so I don't think the problem is in how to display data , I think I miss something in the didselectedrowatindex method

Comment: @MMerou Can you set a breakpoint to see whether the method is even called?